# Does Ubuntu commercial support supports Kubuntu 15.04?

Tags: kubuntu, hardware, support, commercial

Does Ubuntu commercial support supports Kubuntu 15.04? The big difference between Ubuntu an Kubuntu of course KDE desktop, but what if I need support for hardware and interconnect problems (related with services or daemons). Does anyone know about it?

Comment: The base system is still Ubuntu packages, so I would think that they would.

Comment: Kubuntu is not Canonical supported.  Core components such as the kernel and drivers might be, however Kubuntu is a community supported variant and not Canonical supported and it is possible that commercial support will not give full coverage to Kubuntu systems.

Comment: Kubuntu commericial support: http://www.kubuntu.org/support  -> http://kubuntu.emerge-open.com/buy

Comment: Thank you @user26687 please post your answer and I'll accept it